# Importing another py file I wrote with Python to addin wizard py file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I'm going to write an add-in module, I made each combobox from a separate py file. And I got the results I wanted. Now I will transfer them to the py file in the toolbox that I created with an addin_assistant. But when I import the module I created and want the button below to work on the click event, all the add-ins break and do not read the import files.

Do I need to do anything extra to read the import files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can check to troubleshoot this issue:

Make sure that the Python modules you are importing are located in a directory that is on the Python sys.path. You can check the sys.path by printing it in the Python window in ArcGIS:

```py
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

If the directory containing your Python modules is not on the sys.path, you can add it by modifying the sys.path list:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\path\to\your\modules")
```

Make sure that the Python modules you are importing do not have any syntax errors or import errors. You can check for these by running the modules in the Python window in ArcGIS and looking for any error messages.

Make sure that you are using the correct Python version for your ArcGIS Add-In. ArcGIS Add-Ins are built using a specific version of Python, which is specified in the Add-In's configuration file (config.xml). You can check the Python version used by your Add-In by looking at the "Python" element in the config.xml file. The Python version must match the version of Python that is installed on your machine and used by ArcGIS.

If you are still experiencing issues, you can try resetting the ArcGIS Add-In Manager by deleting the AddInManagers folder located in the ArcGIS user profile directory. You can find the location of this folder by running the following code in the Python window in ArcGIS:

```py
import os

import arcpy

print(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()["InstallDir"])
```

The AddInManagers folder is located in the "ArcGIS" subfolder of the directory printed by the above code.

Comment: Thanks, when I did as you said, I was able to do the imports and now I can call the modules I created as I want.